# Blank space to the right of my webpage

Tags: html, css

I am making a webpage. I am the first to admit my CSS skills are not the best. There is blank space appearing to the right side of the whole page. You can scroll over where there is no content. From what I've found on here it may be a problem with `position: absolute;`, but I've tried commenting them out with no luck. Can anyone spot my error?

```css
$icon-font-path:'~bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/';
@import '~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap';
 body {
  font-family: 'Prompt', sans-serif;
  z-index: -1;
}
.landing {
  position: relative;
  background: no-repeat url('http://www.win10themes.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Wallpaper-Weather.jpg') 50% / 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}
.location-search {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#multiple-search-results {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 5%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  clear: both;
}
.multiple-results-list {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
.historical-multiple-results-list {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
.search-label {
  padding-top: 5%;
  margin-right: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.multiple-search-results-heading {
  padding: 5px;
}
.date-picker {
  width: 60%;
  margin-right: 30%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}
.input-group-addon {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.map-container {
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#chart-div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
.landing img {
  position: aboslute;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
  /* max width */
  opacity: 0;
  /* make it transparent */
  z-index: -1;
}
.jumbotron {
  z-index: 5;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(224, 224, 224, .5);
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
}
.current-weather-media-object {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px white solid;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-right: 30%;
}
.card {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px white solid;
  min-height: 375px;
}
.current-weather-media-object img {
  max-width: 150px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-top: 25%;
}
.media-body {
  padding-left: 10%;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.card-img-top {
  max-width: 60%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.card-title {
  font-size: 1em;
}
.card-text {
  font-size: .85em;
}
.media-heading {
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#forecast-results {
  margin-top: 10%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Skycast Inc.</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Prompt" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="vendor.bundle.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" defer></script>
  <script src="bundle.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" defer></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="container-fluid">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li id="li-sign-in"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signInModal">Sign In</a>
              </li>
              <li id="li-sign-up"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signUpModal">Sign Up</a>
              </li>
              <li id="li-sign-out" class="hidden"><a href="#" id="sign-out">Sign Out</a>
              </li>
              <li id="li-change-pw" class="hidden"><a href="#">Change Password</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
  <div class='landing'>
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1>SkyCast Inc.</h1>
      <p>The Forecast Is A Click Away</p>
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button" id="jumbotron-btn">Get Your Local Forecast</a>
    </div>
    <img src="http://www.win10themes.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Wallpaper-Weather.jpg">
    <!-- I'm invisible! yey!-->
  </div>


  <label class='search-label'>Get A Forecast By Locaton</label>
  <div class="input-group location-search">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="location-search-input" placeholder="Enter a location" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2"><button type='click' id="location-search-btn" class='btn btn-primary'>Get Forecast</button></span>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 date-picker">
    <label>Get Data From:</label>
    <input type="date" id="forecast-start-date">
    <br>
    <label>To:</label>
    <input type="date" id="forecast-end-date">
    <br>
    <button type='click' id="historical-location-search-btn" class='btn btn-primary'>Get Historical Data</button>
  </div>

  <div id="multiple-search-results" class="list-group">
  </div>

  <div id="chart-div">
  </div>

  <div id="forecast-results">
  </div>






  <!-- SIGN IN MODAL -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="signInModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Sign In</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form class="form-horizontal" id="sign-in-form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" name="credentials[email]" placeholder="Email">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" name="credentials[password]" placeholder="Password">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox">Remember me
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




  <!-- SIGN UP MODAL -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="signUpModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Sign Up</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form class="form-horizontal" id="sign-up-form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" name="credentials[email]" placeholder="Email">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" name="credentials[password]" placeholder="Password">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" name="credentials[password_confirmation]" placeholder="Password">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox">Remember me
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign Up</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: debugging css without markup is pretty hard

Comment: @Radioreve ok I'll make an edit. Thanks.

Comment: can you give us some html to go with that pls?

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing a working example, but perhaps try adding a `margin: 0;` to the body. (I don't know if that's the white space you mean, but it could be)

Comment: What whitespace do you mean?

Comment: @xufox its not showing up when i execute the snippet here. It is when I serve it on my machine tho.

Comment: You need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the blank space, you must remove margin-right: 50% from the .search-label element. In your case its not needed at all, cause you are making that element 100% wide. Since CSS does not have box sizing value of "margin-box" it will make your element wider than parents content width and thats why you are having extra blank space on the right side.